# Ubuntu 12.04: memory always above 80% and swap around 50-60%

Tags: 12.04, swap, cpu, cpu-load

I have been using ubuntu 12.04 on my system for a long time. Suddenly the system has become too slow and cpu utlization is always above 80%. I have attached the screenshots which displays the usage at a specific time.[image] [image][image]

Comment: For me Firefox with Flash content was a critical thing on Linux. Have you updated flash? Is this effect exist if you do not use any web browser?

Comment: I tried closing firefox but the utlization remained the same

Answer (score 0):

You have many google extentions enabled, tabs or windows and firefox as well
You may have to watch why Chrome is using so much memory.

But I think you should shrink your swap. You have 3.8 memory installed and your swap is 3.8 gb.

Try this:
https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8208-all-about-linux-swap-space

If your swap is encrypted, then follow this guide: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3awww.logilab.org/blogentry/29155&hl=en&tbo=d&strip=1

Edit: I think your CPU is just fine. Your ram is running out of space.
**Edit 2**: Backup your chrome data and install one fresh. However if you have too many apps running with your chrome, I'd check how to backup them properly before anything else.